# Store XML in iOS file System

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I am fetching XML from web service and I want to store an XML into the iOS filesystem.

What should I do for that?

Comment: Google it to find out !

Comment: I did, But I didn't find the proper solution in swift.. Otherwise i would not have put on stackoverflow

Comment: What did you find?  How far have you gotten?  How do you want to store it exactly (there are a handful of options)?